# Button on Left side of Dialog Box in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having a dialog box appeared using jquery like this :

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        title: "Group Invitation",
        width: 600,
        height: 300,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");

                callback(true,myRowID);
            },
            "No": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                callback(false,myRowID);
            }
                        }
    });
```

But my problem is what if I want a button on left side as these both are kept on right side.Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/FJsX3/2/)

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 318,
        width: 531,
        modal: true,
        resize: false,
        buttons: {
            DelUser:{ 
                class: 'alignLeft',
                text: 'Delete User',
                click : function (){
                    alert('delete here');
                }
            },
            "Update User": function () {
                   alert('update here');
       },
            Close: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

CSS:

```
 <style>
   .alignLeft
    {
     margin-right: 170px !important;
    }
 </style>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/akhildave/FJsX3/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the jquery ui button set class.

```
.ui-dialog-buttonset{
float:left !important;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJsX3/)